# Repeat a formula in google sheet within a single cell using different values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So to summarize what i want:
Let's say i have

```
   A         B
1 "Tommy"    "1,2,3"
2 "Berry"    "3,4,5"
3 "Hank"     "1,4,5"
4
5
6 "1"        
7 "5"
```

I would like B6 to show "Tommy Hank" and B7 to show "Berry Hank"

If have managed to create this formula;

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A6,SPLIT(B1, "," , 1,1),0)),"",A1)
```

This formula will give me back the value "Tommy" but not Hank.

I want to list all corresponding A values for every B cell that contains the value "1".

I tried some things with arrayformula like `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A6,SPLIT(B1:B3, "," , 1,1),0)),"",A1:A3)` but i don't really understand what i'm doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to suggest

```
=ArrayFormula(
   textjoin(" ",,
     query(
       {A$1:A$3,","&B$1:B$3&","},
       "select Col1 
        where Col2 contains'"&","&A6&","&"'"
     )
   )
 )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this also works. Also, query looks very interesting. I will dive into that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,
   FILTER($A$1:$A$3,
     BYROW(
       INDEX(
         SPLIT($B$1:$B$3,",")),
       LAMBDA(x,OR(x=A6))
     )
   )
 )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is just what i need. It will take some time to completely understand what is going on there but i will take my time for that.